# DataSet.WriteXml(Stream) vs DataSet.WriteXml(Path)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

So I have run into a peculiar problem. I had been writing and reading datasets without issue when using

```
DataSet.WriteXML(LocalPath)
```

However, I have noticed something when I started using memory streams

```
DataSet.WriteXML(MemoryStream)
```

I ended up losing the declaration portion of the xml document "`<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>`". I referred to the solution on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392626/lost-xml-file-declaration-using-dataset-writexmlstream). However how would I do it if I do not want to use XMLWriter class and set WriteStartDocument to true.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use [DataSet.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws09ehyc.aspx) that takes XmlWriter and configure that XmlWriter with [OmitXmlDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration) to be false it should output that portion.